# I have a variable that is set at 0 and need a line of code to add to the variable by increments of one

Tags: python, variables

I have my variable n = 0, I need a line of code that I can use to keep adding a value to the variable n. I have tried this program:

```
n = 0

sum([n, 1])

print(n)
```

I need the value it prints to be one. What do I need to do?

I also tried using a reduce function as shown below.

```
n = 0

reduce(add,[n, 1])

print(n)
```

The program is printing 0 but it should be adding 1 to the variable n and printing 1 in the example above.

Comment: integers are immutable, you can't change them by passing them to a function, _ever_. For this very case you can try `n = sum([n, 1])` or more simply `n += 1`

Comment: you are not assigning the value back to n when calling this line sum([n, 1])
Try @Jean-FrançoisFabre LOC

Comment: The most simple route is just `n = n + 1`. Where `n += 1` is shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that:

```
n = 0
sum([n, 1])
print(n)
```

doesn't print 1 is because the sum function doesn't change anything. It simply sums up the values in the list provided and returns it.

You didn't store the returned value in any variable so you won't get `1`.

You can fix that by:

```
n = 0
n = sum([n, 1])
print(n)
```

But much efficient and simpler way will be to use the `+` operator and just add one to `n` and store it back into `n`:

```
n = 0
n = n + 1
print(n)
```

Or using the `+=` shortcut which adds the value on the right to the variable on the left and store the result back into the variable on the left:

```
n = 0
n += 1
print(n)
```